Arcpy is throwing error when changing output name for XYTabletoPoint
I have a basic task of lat/lon to xy and I'm trying to name the output shape file in the out_feature_class, when I do it in the gdb file it's fine, but anything else to identify it blows up.
arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(
    in_table = tdf[["Lat","Lon"]],
    out_feature_class = r"R:\Cardiology Hub and Spoke Network Evaluation\04_Quantitative\Data\MapData\CHS_drive_analysis\arcpy.gdb",
    x_field = "Lon",
    y_field = "Lat",
    z_field = None,
    coordinate_system = 'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision'
)

This works fine, but changing to:
out_feature_class = r"R:\Cardiology Hub and Spoke Network Evaluation\04_Quantitative\Data\MapData\CHS_drive_analysis\arcpy.gdb\vet_loc"

Kicks back an "Error in accessing describe error."
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\scripts\XYTableToPoint.py in <module>
    283         arcpy.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 100160)
    284         arcpy.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 192, "{}: {}".format(str(arcpy.GetIDMessage(84526)).lower(), 
--> 285                                            ", ".join(empty_out_bounds)))
    286 
    287     if nulls:

c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\scripts\XYTableToPoint.py in xy_table_to_points(in_table, output_fc, x_field, y_field, z_field, coordinate_system)
    145                 arcpy.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 130006, not_input_sr.name)
    146                 arcpy.AddIDMessage("WARNING", 86114, str(output_fc), createfc_sr.name)
--> 147 
    148     # Create a feature class with the same schema as the input table
    149     template = in_table

ValueError: Object: Error in accessing describe

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ipykernel_2096\970341220.py in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #Need to subet to lat and lon to passs in
----> 2 arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(
      3     in_table = tdf[["Lat","Lon"]],
      4     out_feature_class = r"R:\Cardiology Hub and Spoke Network Evaluation\04_Quantitative\Data\MapData\CHS_drive_analysis\arcpy.gdb\vet_loc",
      5     x_field = "Lon",

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py in XYTableToPoint(in_table, out_feature_class, x_field, y_field, z_field, coordinate_system)
   4980         return retval
   4981     except Exception as e:
-> 4982         raise e
   4983 
   4984 @gptooldoc('XYToLine_management', None)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py in XYTableToPoint(in_table, out_feature_class, x_field, y_field, z_field, coordinate_system)
   4977     from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
   4978     try:
-> 4979         retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.XYTableToPoint_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, out_feature_class, x_field, y_field, z_field, coordinate_system), True)))
   4980         return retval
   4981     except Exception as e:

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py in <lambda>(*args)
    518         val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    519         if callable(val):
--> 520             return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    521         else:
    522             return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)

ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.

*Also the cooridnate_system is a little wild, but I copied that from ArcGIS Pro.
If nothing but the output location changed why is this breaking?
